# zpool import with missing device

Tags: zfs, zpool

I had two geli-encrypted partitions on separate disk in a zpool as simple disks (no raid*). I didn't want redundancy for all files, only for some selected datasets (for which I set copies=2).

Now one disk died (controller doesn't respond anymore), and I'd like to get the files back that are on the remaining disk - but it looks like this is impossible.

```
# zpool import
  pool: data
    id: 9847503418894158179
 state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices are missing from the system.
action: The pool cannot be imported. Attach the missing
        devices and try again.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-6X
config:

        data          UNAVAIL  missing device
          ada0p3.eli  ONLINE

        Additional devices are known to be part of this pool, though their
        exact configuration cannot be determined.

# zpool import -o readonly=on -R /mnt -f data
cannot import 'data': one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

All operations that in some way try to repair a pool require it to be imported, and I can't get import working.

So, finally, the question: is it possible to get those files back without the second disk?

(running debian/kFreeBSD 9.0, ZFS pool version 28)

Comment: You created a zpool that requires both disks to function. It's time to restore from your backups.

Comment: I'd suggest taking this to the [ZFS discussion lists](https://groups.google.com/a/zfsonlinux.org/forum/#!forum/zfs-discuss).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ZFS feature `set copies=2` was not designed to overcome disk failures (see the comments on the following Q&A):

- ServerFault: [How do you restore the correct number of copies after losing a drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/377892/zfs-how-do-you-restore-the-correct-number-of-copies-after-losing-a-drive)

The issue here being that as your pool is made of single disks, **ALL** disks must be healthy for import.

This can only be done in your case by recovering (through backup) the failed disk into a new one.

Comment: Also, I don't think the second disk was unhealthy... just a controller issue. Assuming all disks are physically okay, getting them onto healthy hardware should allow the import.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. While the disk was still spinning with power the controller didn't respond. As the other disk was the same model I tried switching the "controller", but it didn't help.